# Swift Decodable - how to avoid generic type?

Tags: swift, generics, codable, jsonencoder, encodable

I am retrieving a complex nested object from my JSON REST API.

```
DocumentDraft
 - uuid: String
 - schema: Schema // Very complicated object with many variations
 - url: String
 - values: [Value]
 - successors: [String]
 - predecessors: [String]

Value
 - key: String
 - val: String? OR [String]?   // <-- This is the problem
```

I suppose the proper way to deal with this is to introduce a generic type.

```
struct Value<V: Decodable>: Decodable {
  let key: String
  let val: V?
}
```

... but even so, `values` could be a mixed array, so I do not see how declaring what `V` is would help.

But then, of course the generic type propagates all the way up the hierarchy, to the `DocumentDraft` object, to the publisher, to my API calls, etc. polluting the entire chain of otherwise very clean and readable calls and objects. I would like to deal with this only on the level of `Value`, and let the JSONDecoder simply return one of the two somehow.

Is there another way to deal with the two possibilities of the optional `val` as either `String` or `[String]` without changing the entire parent object?

Comment: Send example of your JSON pls

Comment: you can use `enum` with associated value

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that using only the `[String]` type and manually implementing the `init(from:)` function of `Decodable` protocol like this:

```
struct Value: Decodable {
    let key: String
    let val: [String]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key, val
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        key = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .key)
        do {
            if let string = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .val) {
                val = [string]
            } else {
                val = nil
            }
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            val = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .val)
        }
    }
}
```

When decoding to `String` value succeeds, create an array of strings with only one element. When decoding to `String` value fails, try to decode as `[String]`

Comment: This is a great approach, but as written this will ignore malformed JSON when it should throw an error. You can improve this by using a do-catch block rather than if-let and `try decodeIfPresent` rather than `try? decode`.

Comment: @RobNapier you are right. I updated my answer with your suggestion.